# Don't block on receive using UDP in Android

Tags: android, udp

Is it possible to determine whether or not there is data available on a udp socket rather than blocking until data is available? I would like to avoid having to multithread my app as it would introduce complexity - after all, I doubt there are many people who would enjoy needlessly playing with threads and synchronisation!

In C#, for example, I can call socket.Available > 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this were a TCP socket you could do `Socket.getInputStream().available()` but according to your post you are using UDP. Are you sure you really want to be using UDP?

If so - then no, a UDP socket does not have the notion of "available bytes" -- because you aren't really connected to anything on the other side. You're just blindly listening for data to arrive on a specific port. You have to sit and wait for things to arrive. C#'s `socket.Available` is really a facade in this case. It's just telling you the number of bytes left in the socket queue.

You can use Android's async tasks as a simple alternative to building up your own thread and such.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Would Available at least always be > 0 when there's a datagram available?

Comment: In C# yes, but the `Available` thing isn't meant to be used for polling the socket. It's a convenience thing to help you when reading from the socket so that you know how much you can read.

Comment: OK - Is it wise to call receive with a zero ms timeout so that it doesn't pause? If I have to use threading I'll want to use only one in my game loop!

Comment: If it's in a thread (or AsyncTask) you don't need to worry about hanging. Prior to kicking off the task, you'll need to popup some kind of "Please wait..." dialog, otherwise the user will have no idea what's going on. Generally you use a timeout that makes sense for your app. E.g., If the timeout happens, what does that mean for your app?